# Compute limit of piecewise sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Given
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
(1-2^{1-n})x, & -1 \le x \le 0 \\
-\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n+1}-1}x, & 0<x \le 1-2^{-(n+1)} \\
-\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n+1}-1}x+2^{1-n}-2, & 1-2^{-(n+1)} < x < 1 \\
0, & x=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
find $argmin_{x \in [0,1]} f_n(x)$ and $argmin_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)$, where
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)
\end{equation*}
and check whether or not $argmin_{x \in [0,1]} f_n(x) \to argmin_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

First I computed
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & -1 \le x \le 0 \\
-x, & 0<x \le 1-2^{-(n+1)} \\
-x-2, & 1-2^{-(n+1)} < x < 1 \\
0, & x=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
however according to the book it should be
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & -1 \le x \le 0 \\
-x, & 0<x \le 1 \\
0, & x=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
so it appears I have miscalculated the limit in the interval $1-2^{-(n+1)} < x < 1$, however I don't see why the limit is not $-x-2$.

Also, the book says $argmin_{x \in [0,1]}f_n(x)$ does not exist because you can make $f_n(x)$ approach $-\infty$ by making $x \to 1$ on the left. Trying to show this result (by plugging in $x=1$ and hoping to get $-\infty$), I'm getting

\begin{align*}
-\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n+1}-1}+2^{1-n}-2
&=-\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n+1}-1}+\frac{2^{1-n}(2^{n+1}-1)}{2^{n+1}-1}-\frac{2(2^{n+1}-1)}{2^{n+1}-1} \\
&=\frac{-2^{n+1}+2+2^2-2^{1-n}-2^{n+2}-2}{2^{n+1}-1} \\
&=\frac{-2^{n+1}-2^{1-n}-2^{n+2}+4}{2^{n+1}-1}
\end{align*}
but I can't see why this gives $-\infty$. Can anyone see what's gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You most certainly miscalculated $f$, and there is no need to consult the book to realise it: you talk about some $2^{-n-1}$, but said $n$ is never specified. It's not like $f_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The third line in your attempted def'n of $f(x)$ is meaningless because $n\to \infty.$.... Every $x\in (0,1)$ is less than $1-2^{-n-1}$ for all but finitely many $n,$ so by the second line of the def'n of $f_n(x)$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=-x$ for each $x\in (0,1).$... If your only interest is in the point-wise convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $f(x),$ then the third line of the def'n of $f_n(x)$ is irrelevant. (It could be anything.)